# relationship between rdb and sqlite?

Tags: iphone, sqlite, ipad

what is the difference between .rdb and .sqlite?

Answer (score 3):

An .RDB is most likely a Oracle database system which uses SQL commands to access its content. Being simplistic, its big, heavy and powerful and requires servers and services to run and use.

You might look at MySQL for an RDB which carries less weight.

A .sqlite database is a self contained file which can be accessed with an sqlite client or in OS X via the CoreData framework.

The sqlite client also uses SQL commands to access its content but only a subset of the commands that are available to 'true' RDB databases like MySQL or Oracle.

Check out http://www.sqlite.org/ for more info.

Answer (score 1):

A few years later it's also noteworthy that **Redis** uses the .RDB file extension for its dumps (via `SAVE` or `BGSAVE` commands).