# iOS(swift) How to retrieve data from database

Tags: ios, swift

I have .dll file in my project,i want to access the .dll file and retrieve the data from the database fields using swift.i didn't get any idea to retrieve the information.I am new to iOS development any advice would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure `dll` file?

Comment: where did you get this file? You mean this kind of file? http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/736539/MySQL-Data-dll-reference-error

Comment: My colleague created this database i downloaded the database from the server db

Comment: ASk him to provide in .sql format.

Comment: yes now he changed to .rdb

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837501/relationship-between-rdb-and-sqlite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dll(Dynamic-link library) file is a microsoft extension file. It cannot be read in iOS or using swift.

For more information [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10527439/using-a-c-dll-and-lib-in-obj-c-ios)